# TCAM relationships in hardware-switching architecture

Tags: memory, asics, cpu

I am familiar (high level) with how Ternary Content Addressable Memory operates but I remain confused as to how TCAM relates to ASICs and when these components possibly also combine with the CPU for greater switching performance... *(particularly when vendors often market the use of merchant/custom silicon, or custom ASICs for new products & features then it appears confusing)*.

I am familiar in Cisco IOS for example with the ability to partition more space for TCAM performance  for features like qos, acl and route lookups.  I also understand features like NAT will still rely on CPU processing, however i am specifically struggling with;

1. Is TCAM part of the same hardware architecture, i.e. internal or
   external to the ASIC itself?
2. Are TCAMs scalable (for example can manufacturers just keep adding TCAMs to a platform for greater performance & custom features) or is there a limit based on things like power consumption?
3. Do TCAM cycles and ASICs work in parallel with the CPU at all for features like
   NAT or should I only think of them as independent things?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[TCAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content-addressable_memory#Ternary_CAMs) is a type of memory, which takes 10-12 transistors to store a single bit. By way of comparison, Static RAM ([SRAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_random-access_memory)) only takes 6 transistors to store a single bit, and Dynamic RAM ([DRAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_random-access_memory)) takes one transistor and a capacitor.  All these different types of memories can either be internal or external to an ASIC. One reason to put all memories on a chip, is that they can be ran at higher clock rates than when external to a chip. Why choose one type of memory over another? This has to do with characteristics of the memory, [SRAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_random-access_memory) can be accessed every clock, [DRAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_random-access_memory) requires periodic refresh, so can not be accessed every clock and [TCAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content-addressable_memory#Ternary_CAMs) gives you [ternary capability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation).

[TCAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content-addressable_memory#Ternary_CAMs)s are as scalable as long as you have space on a chip to instantiate them, or pins on package to connect to external ones. The issue with [TCAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content-addressable_memory#Ternary_CAMs) is they take 2x space of [SRAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_random-access_memory), and 12x space of [DRAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_random-access_memory). It does not always make sense to use [TCAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content-addressable_memory#Ternary_CAMs) for the same operations that you can do them algorithmically (Hashes, *tries) with other memory types. It comes down to a tradeoff between utilization effectiveness of the algorithm and space on the chip on which one to choose. [TCAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content-addressable_memory#Ternary_CAMs)'s power utilization grows in linear proportion to size. The majority of large [TCAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content-addressable_memory#Ternary_CAMs)s (greater than 2M entries) now use algorithmic techniques so that power savings can be achieved.

NAT/PAT is complex feature, which generally needs a CPU or Network Processor (NPU) to handle fixups. The general packet flow for NAT is first packet goes to CPU/NPU, and a flow entry is installed in flow table or ACL table with the information on how to translate subsequent packets in the flow. There are multiple different forms of NAT/PAT, and just as many ways to optimize each one in a chip. The simplest NAT being rewrite the IPs, and don't worry if you break the addresses embedded in the payload, no fixups.

There is another version of BRKARC-3466 which was presented at CiscoLive 2013 in Melbourne that covers some of the high level ideas behind lookups, which is missing from the 2013 Orlando one. A good reference book on this area is [Network Algorithmics: An Interdisciplinary Approach to Designing Fast Networked Devices](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0120884771) by George Varghese.

Answer (score 4):

ASIC can be thought of as a kind of chip. It is normally built in order to do something in hardware that otherwise would be done is software. So Cisco can build an ASIC for anything it wants. Depending on the model of the switch there is 1 or many ASICs. TCAM is a memory design since it is usually found on the chassis systems it is implemented as 1 of many asics. TCAM is used for particular lookup functions like routing (CEF) or ACLS, so if an ASIC does not need to do that kind of lookup it works separately from TCAM. On the other hand ASICs that handle QoS marking work hand in glove with TCAM. The presentation below on cisco live discusses some of the design tradeoffs, and a good place to look to get an understanding of what goes into switch design

BRKARC-3466 -  Exploring the engineering behind the making of a switch (2013 Orlando) it contains lists of the asics and a lot of general switch design information